# How do I get commenters for a blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails 3.2.

I have following models:

```
Blog
Comment
User

class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

I want a list of commenters for a given blog.

I want something like

```
   class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :comments
      has_many :commenters, ...fill in the blank...
    end
```

`@blog.commenters` should return an array of User instances.

What should I fill the blanks with above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have the following

```
class User
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :user
end

class Blog
  has_many :comments
end
```

All you need to add is

```
class Blog
  has_many :commenters, :through => :comments, :source => :user
end
```

Note: the `:source` is needed because the relation on `comments` is not called `commenters`